# Query to get Last month's Data in DB2

Tags: db2

I need to fetch last 2 months data in DB2 environment ,What is the query? The dates are changing ,so ,it must be dynamic.

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working?  We don't know your data, we can't really tell you what query you need.  Did you mean to ask someone on your internal team instead?

Comment: There are already several answers to similar questions on SO.

Comment: I am asking just a generic query. Actually , I have to get recent 2 month data from the table and this needs to be done dynamically.

Comment: I have done this in SQL SERVER but in DB2 I am not getting

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get latest dates which are dynamically inserted then do something like below

```
select * from ur_table where urdate between (select max(urdate)- 2 months from urtable) and (select max(urdate) from urtable)
```

Comment: I need all data ,between 2 months ,dynamic.

Comment: @PujaMishra plz check now